# Convert list to dictionary using string Expression c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dictionary, lambda, expression

I need to convert a list into a Dictionary.  This can be done in c# by using the following syntax

```
var dictionary = myList.ToDictionary(e => e.Id);
```

I do not know the name of the id field, as i am creating some code to iterate through an object and its child objects/lists and attach them to my dbcontext.

I have already got code to determine the name of the property that is my key value, but for testing i can just use "Id" (others may differ)

So i need to basically create this string "c => e.Id" to a Func, but i am unsure what parameters are for what `Expression` objects.

So far i have this

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> strToFunc<T>(string propName)
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> func = null;

        var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);
        ParameterExpression tpe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var left = Expression.Property(tpe, prop);


    return func;
}
```

Someone who is an expert in Expressions, would really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe have a look at [dynamic linq](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/). It might just be what you are looking for.

Comment: In a test program write `Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>> tmp = x => x.SomeProperty;`, you will be able to look a the `tmp` object in the debugger and that will help you figure out what pieces you need. Also, why is your function `<T, bool>` If you are trying to make a expression I would expect `<TKey, TValue>`

Comment: Correct me if I misunderstood the question, but if you know the name of the property that contains the key values, what's stopping you from doing something like `var dictionary = myList.ToDictionary(e => e.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(e));`?

Comment: Can you post an example of how you want to call the method?

Comment: @Innat3 This would of been great, but some of my objects have more than 1 keyName property.  Else that would of been perfect

Comment: @user2736022 so in those cases, how would you construct the dictionary key? by concatenating the values of these properties into a single string?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question this is how I would do it, hope it helps some how if not.

```
public static Dictionary<object, TValue> GenericToDictionary<TValue>(this IEnumerable<TValue> source, string propName)
{
    Dictionary<object, TValue> result = new Dictionary<object, TValue>();
    foreach (var obj in source)
    {
        result[obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(obj)] = obj;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the property name as a string, you could try this.

```
public static Dictionary<string, T> ListToDictionary<T>(string propertyName, List<T> list)
    {
        Func<T, string> func = obj => typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj) as string;
        return list.ToDictionary(func);
    }
```

Otherwise you can just pass the expression to a lambda:

```
class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        var people = new List<Person>();
        var dict = people.ToDictionary(p => p.ID);
    }
```